# How to add values from sheet 1 and present total amount on sheet 2?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the following two sheets in the same Excel workbook:

Expenses

```
    A       B
1 report  amount
2 0402    10.00
3 0402    15.00
4 0402     5.00
5 1156    40.00
6 1156    30.00
```

Payouts

```
    A       B
1 report  total
2 0402    30.00
3 1156    70.00
```

I'm looking for the formula for cells `Payouts!B2` and further down. As can be seen, these cells should just add up the expenses from sheet 1. I have tried for `Payouts!B2`

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Expenses'!A1:B6, 'Expenses!'2, FALSE);
```

But this keeps returning the "there is an error" popup without any further information. What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Do you want a formula or would you be happy to use a pivot table? A pivot table would do this for you 'automatically'

Comment: Well, VLOOKUP won't be evaluating the sum, but returns only the first value it will find and if you correct your formula, you will get 10.00 for 0402 and 40.00 for 1156. The error is that the 3rd parameter should be only `2` (no sheet reference). Otherwise, I suggest using a pivottable as CodeBeard mentioned.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Expenses'!A1:B6, 'Expenses!'2, FALSE);` there is an error in this line. The second 'Expenses!' is not needed. I think you just want a 2. I don't think this will solve your problem - but it will get rid of the error message.

Comment: The formula will get very involved IMO. A pivot table is super easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, since you prefer a formula, the formula that would do the sum you need is `=SUMIF()`.

```
=SUMIF(Expenses!A1:A6, A2, Expenses!B1:B6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a pivot table for this:

[image]

The pivot table above covers the data set in the range A1:C6 with row labels given by `report` and values given by the sum of `amount`. I've also changed the number format to include 2 decimals.